# Sencha CMD for EXT JS (GPL - Version)

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I used the EXT JS 6.2 (GPL) in combination with Sencha CMD 6.5 but encountered various problems.

Which Sencha CMD version do I need (is recommended) in order to properly work with EXT JS (GPL) version?

Comment: Cmd 6.5.3 and ExtJS 6.2.1 (both commercial and GPL) are working together just fine. Could you elaborate on the "various problems"?

Comment: Now, it seems to work but I do not know why. Very often I had the problem: "no .sencha directory"